# Ember - What's the difference between controller's content and model property

Tags: javascript, ember.js

In ember's official guide, it provides two ways to set the controller's underlying object.
First is setting the model property:

```
App.SongsRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    setupController: function(controller, playlist) {
        controller.set('model', playlist.get('songs'));
    }
});
```

Second is setting the content property:

```
MyApp.listController = Ember.ArrayController.create();

$.get('people.json', function(data) {
    MyApp.listController.set('content', data);
});
```

Are these two properties represent the same thing? Which way should i use?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It seems they are the same thing,

https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/blob/v1.3.0/packages/ember-runtime/lib/controllers/controller.js#L44

```
Ember.ControllerMixin = Ember.Mixin.create(Ember.ActionHandler, {
....
model: Ember.computed.alias('content'),
....
```

The `model` property is an alias for `content`.

Also,

https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/blob/v1.3.0/packages/ember-routing/lib/system/route.js#L849

which mentions that,

> ```
> By default, the `setupController` hook sets the `content` property of
> the controller to the `model`.
> ```

**UPDATE**
Deprecated since v1.7.0 and the code placed in a mixin.
https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/blob/v2.12.0/packages/ember-runtime/lib/mixins/controller.js
Along with the related deprecation mixin.
https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/blob/v2.12.0/packages/ember-runtime/lib/mixins/controller_content_model_alias_deprecation.js

Comment: Yes this is correct. To give a little more detail, this change was made to make the API more consistent. E.g. think of the `model` hook in Routes. It is more consistent that the result of this hook gets set as the model property of the matching controller instead of the old content property. The alias is still there for backwards compatbility. **You should always use the model property.**

Comment: from Ember.ArrayController source: `content: Ember.computed(function() { return Ember.A(); }),` can anyone explain this?

Answer (score 1):

In the documentation - http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Controller.html#property_model - it clearly states that when retrieving or modifying a controller's model, the model property should be used instead of the content property.