# Ember.js: Are these .pushObject() calls synonymous?

Tags: javascript, ember.js

In my Ember app, I've got an ArrayController in which I am adding and removing records from the store. In playing around with adding the record, once created, to my ArrayController, the following three statements appear to do the same thing.

```
 App.MyItemController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({

   ...
   var newItem = this.store.createRecord('item', {...});

   // do these lines do the same thing?
   this.pushObject(newItem);

 });
```

Are these calls synonymous with the above? These all seem to work the same, and add it visibly to the template and will remove upon the action to remove the item. Or, what's the difference?

```
   this.get('model').pushObject(newItem);
   this.get('content').pushObject(newItem);
```

This is a question in the spirit of increasing mutual understanding. Thank you for any answers!

Comment: look here please http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21018683/ember-whats-the-difference-between-controllers-content-and-model-property/21019493#21019493

Comment: Yes they are synonymous.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They do work the same, but the don't have to. To explain:

`ArrayController` is a combination of `ArrayProxy` and `ControllerMixin`. So...

1. The first way you used, `this.pushObject()`, comes from `ArrayProxy`. It acts just like an array, so has all of the array methods. In the background, this call *does* modify the `content` property, but that is an implementation detail. Which brings me to...
2. `this.get('content').pushObject()` is an implementation detail. The `ArrayProxy` is proxying the `content` property, but that doesn't have to be so. Ember could change it tomorrow to proxy the `proxy_content` property instead. (Don't worry, they won't.) The point is that you should consider the `content` property private API.
3. `this.get('model').pushObject()` is probably the one you want to use. `model` comes from `ControllerMixin` and is public API. `model` and `content` are the same here, but again, they don't have to be. This method makes it very explicit that you're modifying your model. It also remains functional if you change your implementation. (For instance, if you switch to an `ObjectController`, it will still work.)

I'm being a bit nit-picky, I just thought I'd try to explain the true differences. Use whichever one you'd like, but if you're anal like me and love to do the 'right' thing, use the third method.

Comment: Not nitpicky. I like your recommendation. Thanks!