# How to bind-attr class active in EmberJS based on an array and a value?

Tags: javascript, arrays, ember.js

I have a `mode` array and wants to set the active `li` based on the active property.

```
mode: ['list', 'grid', 'table'], // dynamic values
active: 'list',
```

For output:

```
<ul>
{{#each mode}}
    <li {{bind-attr class="?:active"}}>
        <a href="#">{{this}}</a>
    </li>
{{/each}}
</ul>
```

What will I put on the bind-attr part so that if the `active` property is set on any one of the `mode` array, it will bind an active class on the `li`?

Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a child controller and add a computed property to indicate is active or not:

The ul controller(Use ApplicationController here for simplicity):

```
App.ApplicationController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
    mode: ['list', 'grid', 'table'],
    active: 'list'
});
```

The li controller:

```
App.LiController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
    needs: ['application'],

    isActive: function() {
        return this.get('controllers.application.active') === this.get('model');
    }.property()
});
```

The template:

```
<ul>
    {{#each mode itemController="li"}}
    <li {{bind-attr class="isActive:active"}}>
        <a href="#">{{model}}</a>
    </li>
    {{/each}}
</ul>
```

[JSBin](http://emberjs.jsbin.com/qomoroje/3/edit)

Why do i need another controller?

From ember's doc, it says:

> In Ember.js, controllers allow you to decorate your models with display logic. In general, your models will have properties that are saved to the server, while controllers will have properties that your app does not need to save to the server.

So, the extra controller's only purpose is to hold the `isActive` property.

What is `{{content}}` for?

`content` represents the controller's underlying object, in this case a string literal. It's not a reserved  keyword, it's controller's property.

I updated my answer to use `model` instead of `content`, actually they are the same thing, you should always use the `model` property. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21018683/ember-whats-the-difference-between-controllers-content-and-model-property)

Comment: Perfect! I have few questions though if you don't mind. Why do I need another controller? What is {{content}} for? Is this a reserved keyword? Thanks again @merlin