# EmberJS: bootstrap modal refuses to re-open due to record not being correctly deleted?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, ember.js, ember-data

### The Goal:

The thing that I am really trying to accomplish here is gain an understanding how to work with model records cleanly.  In this particular case, these records are kind of "one-offs".  If the modal is closed without saving, then they are meant to be cleared from memory... and once a record is saved to the server there is also no need to keep the re record stored client side.

**Description:**

I created a button action that transitions into a "payment" route, which renders inside a Bootstrap modal.

This route creates a "payment" record and also pulls a list of available "debts" the payment can be applied to.

```
App.PaymentRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
    console.log('( Router: Model Hook )--------------------)');
    return this.store.createRecord('payment');
  },
  afterModel: function() {
    console.log('( Router: AfterModel Hook )--------------------)');
    var route = this;
    return Ember.RSVP.hash({
      debt_list: this.store.find('debt', { account_id: 36, page_size: 100, page_number: 1 })
    }).then(function(hash) {
      route.setProperties({
        account_id: 36,
        debt_list: hash.debt_list
      });
    });
  },
  setupController: function(controller, model) {
    console.log('( Router: SetupController Hook )--------------------)');
    this._super(controller, model);
    controller.setProperties({
      account_id: this.get('account_id'),
      debt_list: this.get('debt_list')
    });
  },
});
```

Closing the modal should delete the current record and transition back to index...

```
actions: {
    removeModal: function() {
      this.currentModel.deleteRecord();
      this.transitionTo('index');
      return true;
    }
  }
```

when payment button is clicked a second time, it "should" create a new payment record... but instead an error occurs, because the previous record has not been correctly cleared?

I successfully recreated the issue in this [JSBin](http://emberjs.jsbin.com/becece/1/)

Am i not creating and deleting records correctly?

***Side Note:***

I have set `console.log()` on all my route and controller methods... I noticed that `setupController` does not fire on the second open attempt.... also my controller cp's and observers are triggering multiple times during the initialization proces... i dont know if that is contributing to the problem or not?

Comment: you just need to rollback the record before you remove it.

Comment: i tried what you suggested.  i get a similar error... it cannot handle `deleteRecord` while in state `root.deleted.saved` <-- after rollback

Comment: Any chance you can recreate your problem in an ember app and put it up on git?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you actually want to 'delete' the record. What you want to do is rollback any changes to it and then unload it.  I would do this in your `willTransition` hook on the route so no-matter how you leave the route, the model will be unloaded.

Code:

```
willTransition: function(transition) {
  var model = this.currentModel;
  var debt_list = get(this, 'debt_list');
  var store = this.store;

  // dispose of models after views have been finalised 
  Ember.run.once(function() {
    if (model) {
      model.rollback();
      store.unloadRecord(model);
    }
    if (debt_list) {
      debt_list.forEach(function(debt) {
        debt.rollback();
        store.unloadRecord(debt);
      });
    }
  }
}
```

**UPDATE:** It is important to unload records from the ember run-loop to give any views bound to those records a chance to be torn down before ripping models out from under them.  That is why the model disposing is performed within `Ember.run.once()`.

Another observation is that you should be able kick off the `debt_list` request in your `model` hook using `RSVP.hash`.  So putting it all together your route should look something like the following:

```
var get = Ember.get, set = Ember.set;

App.PaymentRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function(params, transition, queryParams) {
    return Ember.RSVP.hash({
      content: this.store.createRecord('payment'),
      debt_list: this.store.find('debt', { account_id: 36, page_size: 100, page_number: 1 })
    });
  },

  setupController: function(controller, hash) {
    if (controller && hash) {
      controller.setProperties(hash);
      set(controller, 'account_id', 36);
    }
  },

  actions: {

    willTransition: function(transition) {
      var hash = this.currentModel;
      var store = this.store;

      // tell controller to reset/cleanup - you should set any
      // model related properties ie 'content'/'model' and 'debt_list'
      // to null/default values.
      this.controller.reset();

      if (hash) 
        // dispose of models after views have been finalised 
        Ember.run.once(function() {
          hash.content.rollback();
          store.unloadRecord(hash.content);
          hash.debt_list.forEach(function(debt) {
            debt.rollback();
            store.unloadRecord(debt);
          });
        });
      }
    }
  }
});
```

I have updated your JSBin [here](http://jsbin.com/niqoletoca/1#/) so its working perfectly, models are correctly removed from the store.

Comment: That sounds pretty clear, i never realized there was an `unloadRecord`.  And what is the significance of setting the `content` property as opposed to `model` property?  I know it is an alias of model, but i was hesitant because i thought i would wind up needing to reference my model like `content.myProperties` or something strange like that?

Comment: @Grapho 'content' is what ember sets by default, 'model' is an alias. There is a good SO answer on content vs model here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21018683/ember-whats-the-difference-between-controllers-content-and-model-property

Comment: @Grapho Also remember controllers are proxies to their 'content' so you don't have to worry about using 'content.foo' or 'model.foo' just 'foo' unless you have defined a 'foo' property on your controller and need to explicitly get to the underlying content/model property.

Comment: your answer is very close to what i want... however the only thing i still notice is that on everytime i open the modal a new record is created.  Unload doesnt seem to remove the record from the store?  I can see in ember inspector that the count keeps going up an up *(not sure if that would cause probelms or no?)*.  I give you credit for solving the error part however!

Comment: OK you may need to clear content and debt_list properties on your controller as route controllers are singleton instances and persist in your applicarion once instantiated. That may be why the models are hanging around.

Comment: @Grapho ok updated answer, everything is functioning correctly.

Comment: Thanks again! This was exactly what I needed.  I am using this method for all my `createRecord` routes now!

Answer (score 2):

The problem seems to be the `this.store.find('debt', { account_id: 36, page_size: 100, page_number: 1 })`

Because ember data will load the items into the store once the query finishes, and the controller is bound to that array, when it changes all observers are fired.

so `setDebtPayments` is getting called, (before setupController), trying to do `model.set('payment_debts', paymentDebts);` which at that point is already destroyed.

I [managed to fix this](http://jsbin.com/ziket/3) (suboptimaly) by creating a new payment record when `removeModal` is called.

Another option, is to check if there is a model decorated by the controller, before doing anything with it:  http://jsbin.com/ziket/8

Comment: well, it is a start at least :)  The problem i see now is that the records increment up and up... so if you keep opening and closing, we will soon end up with 4, 5, 6 "orphaned" records.  I will give it a test in some live code to see if that has any adverse effects.

Comment: Yeah, I dont understand why `destroyRecord` is not removing the payment from the store.

Comment: Do you suppose there is a way to control my observers with Ember.run, so that they wont fire until the controller is re-set?

Comment: I think what I might need to do, is put all this logic into a component.  THe observer will keep trying to push those objects into a model attribute otherwise.  Putting it into a component should ensure that the logic wont fire until the component is rendered to the template... allowing setupController to work as needed.

Comment: that could work too, also, do you need to load the debt_list every time? as it is now, it will make the call everytime.

Comment: i do need to call it every time. reason 1: the modal could be opened from a different "account", and reason 2: a new debt could be added in a different part of the system (not ember)